# Elementwise logical operation on character with pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am working with a data frame where each entry is a character from A-E representing different intensity level

For example:

data frame

```
df=

        1   2   3
    0   C   C   A
    1   0   D   B
    2   E   0   A
```

I want to threshold the data at different intensity level from A to E into a binary matrix. Thus, I want to perform an element-wise comparison.

If it's a number, it's simply: `df > 0`
However, when I tried with a character, `df > 'A'` , an error is thrown `"TypeError: Could not compare ['A'] with block values"`

I can of course do a 'for' loop but is there any one line, elegant solution to perform element-wise logical operation with character using data frame in pandas?

Comment: what is your Pandas version? `df > 'A'` works just fine for me (Pandas 0.21.1)

Comment: mine is '0.20.3'. I will do an update and let you know if it works.

Comment: One thing you may want to pay special attention to is the behavior you want to see when you compare 0 with letters. If `'A' > 0` is `TRUE` for you, then updating Pandas will solve the issue. If not, first treat the 0's.

Comment: yes, I've upgraded to '0.21.1' and the logical operation `df > 'A' ` can be performed now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider the following bit more generic approach:

```
In [238]: df.astype(str).applymap(ord).sub(ord('@')).replace(-16,0)
Out[238]:
   1  2  3
0  3  3  1
1  0  4  2
2  5  0  1
```

where:

```
0 - 0
1 - A
2 - B
3 - C
...
```

Comment: I tried your generic approach but received this error `TypeError: ('ord() expected string of length 1, but int found', 'occurred at index 1')`

Comment: @tlemau, you have a mixture of numbers and strings - i have updated my answer - please check...

Comment: got it. Thank you very much! What if the data contains not just integer 0 but also 0.0? When I run with that data, then the error now is due to the length of 0.0 which is 3 characters. `('ord() expected a character, but string of length 3 found', 'occurred at index 3')`. I used pandas.csv_read() and the types of the data is not properly casted yet.

Comment: @tlemau, you may try this: `df.astype(str).applymap(lambda s: ord(s[0])).sub(ord('@')).replace(-16,0)`

Answer (score 0):

Simply upgrade Pandas version to 0.21.1 and it works.